# Creating slices of dataframe groupby groups

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a Dataframe with 3 columns - location_id, customers, cluster.
Previously, I clustered by data into 5 clusters. Hence, the cluster column contain values [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

I would like to separate each cluster into 2 slices for my next stage of testing. E.g. 50-50 slice, or 30-70 slice, or 20-80 slice.

Question - How do I apply a function that adds a column to
`data.groupby('cluster')`?

Ideal Result

```
  location_id        customers  cluster  slice
0       149213        132817       1       1
1       578371        76655        1       0
2        91703        74048        2       1 
3       154868        62397        2       1
4      1022759        59162        2       0
```

**Update**

@MaxU's solution put me on the right path. The solution involves using dataframe.assign function to add a new column, and a check for current index/ total index length to assign a slice of the correct proportions. However, the code below somehow did not work for me. I ended up splitting up the @MaxU's solution into separate steps and that worked.

```
testgroup= (data.groupby('cluster')
.apply(lambda x: x.assign(index1=(np.arange(len(x))))
))
testgroup= (testgroup.groupby('cluster')
.apply(lambda x: x.assign(total_len=len(x))
))

testgroup['is_slice'] = ((testgroup['index1']/testgroup['total_len']) <= 0.5)

            location_id  customers  cluster  index1  total_len  is_slice

    0        149213        132817        1     0     12   True
    1        578371         76655        1     1     12   True
    2         91703         74048        1     2     12   True
    3        154868         62397        1     3     12   True
    4       1022759         59162        1     4     12   True
    5         87016         58134        1     5     12   True
    6        649432         56849        1     6     12   False
    7        219163         56802        1     7     12   False
    8         97704         54718        1     8     12   False
    9        248455         52806        1     9     12   False
    10       184828         52783        1    10     12   False
    11       152887         52565        1    11     12   False
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your original DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

let's make your sample DF bit larger:

```
In [31]: df = pd.concat([df] * 3, ignore_index=True)

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
    location_id  customers  cluster
0        149213     132817        1
1        578371      76655        1
2         91703      74048        2
3        154868      62397        2
4       1022759      59162        2
5        149213     132817        1
6        578371      76655        1
7         91703      74048        2
8        154868      62397        2
9       1022759      59162        2
10       149213     132817        1
11       578371      76655        1
12        91703      74048        2
13       154868      62397        2
14      1022759      59162        2
```

slice 30-70:

```
In [34]: (df.groupby('cluster')
    ...:    .apply(lambda x: x.assign(slice=((np.arange(len(x))/len(x)) <= 0.3).astype(np.uint8)))
    ...:    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[34]:
    location_id  customers  cluster  slice
0        149213     132817        1      1
1        578371      76655        1      1
5        149213     132817        1      0
6        578371      76655        1      0
10       149213     132817        1      0
11       578371      76655        1      0
2         91703      74048        2      1
3        154868      62397        2      1
4       1022759      59162        2      1
7         91703      74048        2      0
8        154868      62397        2      0
9       1022759      59162        2      0
12        91703      74048        2      0
13       154868      62397        2      0
14      1022759      59162        2      0
```

slice 20-80:

```
In [35]: (df.groupby('cluster')
    ...:    .apply(lambda x: x.assign(slice=((np.arange(len(x))/len(x)) <= 0.2).astype(np.uint8)))
    ...:    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[35]:
    location_id  customers  cluster  slice
0        149213     132817        1      1
1        578371      76655        1      1
5        149213     132817        1      0
6        578371      76655        1      0
10       149213     132817        1      0
11       578371      76655        1      0
2         91703      74048        2      1
3        154868      62397        2      1
4       1022759      59162        2      0
7         91703      74048        2      0
8        154868      62397        2      0
9       1022759      59162        2      0
12        91703      74048        2      0
13       154868      62397        2      0
14      1022759      59162        2      0
```