# How to slice a PandasGroupByObject and use multiple functions in agg

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with `Data` and `Group`s and I want to perform multiple functions using the `agg`-method.

```
from scipy.stats import iqr, norm
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[1,2,3,5,10,5,3,3,4,1], 'Group':[1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1]})
df.groupby('Group')['Data'].agg(['median', iqr])
```

which works fine. But now I want to slice the groups befor I perform the operations.

The problem is, that

```
df.groupby('Group')['Data'].iloc[2:-2].agg(['median', iqr])
```

thows an error because slicing is not supported for PandasGroupByObjects. An error comes for

```
df.groupby('Group')['Data'].nth[2:-2].agg(['median', iqr])
```

too, because the combinations is not allowed.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236925/slicing-a-datagramegroupby-object) shows that a `lambda function` can be used to slice the values.

I tried to use this, but

```
df.groupby('Group')['Data'].agg(lambda x: [np.median(x.iloc[2:-2]), iqr(x.iloc[2:-2])])
```

returns a DataFrames with lists in it, which is not what I want.

How to apply the slicing and get a well formated DataFrame as return value?

Wanted output:

```
       median  iqr
Group             
1        10.0  0.0
2         3.0  0.0
```

Comment: kindly add the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many groups or many functions to apply, one option is a double `groupby`:

```
(df.groupby('Group', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda g: g.iloc[2:-2])
   .groupby('Group')['Data']
   .agg(['median', iqr])
)
```

Efficiency will depend on the number of functions and groups.

output:

```
       median  iqr
Group             
1        10.0  0.0
2         3.0  0.0
```

##### timings

The double `groupby` is less efficient than [named aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73499391/16343464) for few functions and few groups, but more efficient for many of either, which is expected as the slicing is performed **once** for the double `groupby` vs **as many times as there are groups × aggregations functions** (although on a smaller size) in the other case.

Provided example:

```
# double groupby
2.43 ms ± 554 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# lambdas with named aggregation
2.39 ms ± 867 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

100k rows, 2 groups, 2 aggregations:

```
# double groupby
12.1 ms ± 913 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# lambdas with named aggregation
8.12 ms ± 1.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

100k rows, 2 groups, 100 aggregations:

```
# double groupby
149 ms ± 22.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# lambdas with named aggregation
300 ms ± 34.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

100k rows, 52 groups, 5 aggregations:

```
# double groupby
30.1 ms ± 4.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# lambdas with named aggregation
52.2 ms ± 10.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

100k rows, 52 groups, 100 aggregations:

```
# double groupby
220 ms ± 24.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# lambdas with named aggregation
837 ms ± 109 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks like this works, but this might be ineffectiv.

```
df.groupby('Group')['Data'].agg(
    median=lambda x: np.median(x.iloc[2:-2]),
    iqr=lambda x: iqr(x.iloc[2:-2])
)
```

Which gives:

```
       median  iqr
Group             
1        10.0  0.0
2         3.0  0.0
```

Comment: I added an alternative and a few timings. In any case one should always test on the real dataset